# HttpGet, вываливается в исключение

Tags: android

Дурацкий вопрос:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
String targetUrl = "http://192.168.1.6/list.php";
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(targetUrl);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = client.execute(httpGet);
```

На `client.execute(httpGet)` вываливается исключение. В манифесте стоит доступ к интернет. Грешил на GenyMotion, но при загрузке программы на телефон аналогичная ситуация.
Please help!

Comment: Стектрейс покажите. android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того, какая ошибка - посмотрите в окне вывода, только вот 192.168.1.6 - это вроде как локальный адрес, вряд ли вы получите с этого адреса какие-либо данные.

Comment: В браузере эмулятора, адрес, открывается корректно. Пробовал сделать в asynctask, аналогичная ошибка